# How to use API with token in getting/posting/putting data?

Tags: angular, api, http

How can we use API that has token in angular 2?

consider my example below..

root url: http://awesomedommain.com/test/api/mytest/
Token: ZfGwMSgzMDo4ODkyZDgyNS1jZTQDLFs0SGEtOTNlOS04ZTI1AWI4SW332Dd0c2Fm

how can i use this with the http?

Comment: Do you want to pass the token in the header?

Comment: yes, but i dont know how to do it using angular 2

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass token in Angular 2.

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Token': 'ZfGwMSgzMDo4ODkyZDgyNS1jZTQDLFs0SGEtOTNlOS04ZTI1AWI4SW332Dd0c2Fm' });

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this._http.post("api/YourApi", formData, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the token in the header of your API request like this in your `app.service.ts`:

```
request() {
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Token': "ZfGwMSgzMDo4ODkyZDgyNS1jZTQDLFs0SGEtOTNlOS04ZTI1AWI4SW332Dd0c2Fm",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    return this.http.get("http://awesomedommain.com/test/api/mytest/", { headers: headers })
      .map(
        res => res.json()
      )
      .catch(
        err => Observable.throw(err || "Server error")
      );
  }
```

To do the request you need to inject the Angular Http service and Headers like this:

`import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';`

and in your constructor like this:

```
constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }
```

Comment: Thanks, for this @Ma Kobi. i will try this one.